Exercise 7.14 First course in probability
Exercise 7.14 First course in probability :

An urn has $m$ black balls. At each stage, a black ball is removed and
a new ball that is black with probability $p$ and white with
probability $1 - p$ is put in its place. Find the expected number of
stages needed until there are no more black balls in the urn.

My idea of using conditional expectation:
Let us denote $X$ as number of stages needed and $E(X) = E_m$
$$E(X) = E(X|V)P(V) + E(X|\bar{V})P(\bar{V})$$
where $V$ is the event that in  the first stage, we receive a black ball.
So: $E_m = pE_m + (1-p)E_{m-1}$, since we only pick black balls each stage.
We conclude: $E_m = E_0 = 0$ !! This is wrong.
The correct answer is: $\frac{m}{1-p}$. Where am I going wrong here?

My advice would be: Pick a small $m=1,2,3$ and say $p=1/2$ or $p=1/4$ and just draw a tree diagram on a paper and make some observations.

You forget that after the first substitution we are one stage further. Actually: $E_m=p(1+E_m)+(1-p)(1+E_{m-1})=1+pE_m+(1-p)E_{m-1}$. This will simplify things.

Right XD. "Subtle"

This is essentially a geometric process. You expect it to take $\frac 1{1-p}$ trials to get the first White, and the rest follows.

@lulu Thanks! That's another way to solve it

Here is the outline for my intuitive way to get the answer :
Number of stages to get $m$ White Balls is $S(m)$
Then we get $S(m)=S(1)+S(m-1)$
That will then give $S(m)=S(1)+S(1)+S(m-2)$
Eventually we will get $S(m)=mS(1)$
Evaluating $S(1)$ is well-known.
It involves considering the events like this :
$1:W$
$2:BW$
$3:BBW$
$4:BBBW$
$5:BBBBW$
$6:BBBBBW$
$7:BBBBBBW$
$8:BBBBBBBW$
Probability for $n$ stages is $P(n)=p^{n-1}q^{1}$ where $q=1-p$
Add $nP(n)$ for $n=0$ to $n=\infty$ to get $S(1)$
We will get $1/q$
Multiply that by $m$ to get $S(m)$
We will get $m/q$
